# Should I implement Eureka Discovery Server

Tags: spring, microservices, openshift, netflix-eureka

I manage an application which is a suite of microservices(Spring) deployed and running on OpenShift. Each of the micro-services talk to each other via Load Balanced URLs. This load balancer is a corporate managed load balancer. I am aware that OpenShift has an internal DNS which resolves the service URLs to IPs.

Does it make sense to implement an Eureka Discovery Server considering the OpenShift DNS server is already supposed to do what the Discovery server will do ?

Note: The reason i am considering Eureka implementation is because off-late I am seeing some performance issues with DNS name resolution, where the first request to a particular micro-service is considerably slow.

Comment: I don't see how Eureka can help for your use case. Also generally, OpenShift / Kubernetes pretty much makes Eureka obsolete imo.